# Extract XML using PLSQL based upon child element value

Tags: sql, xml, xpath, plsql

I have the following XML document stored in a clob variable within my PLSQL procedure:

```
 <soap:Envelope>
 <soap:Body>
 <ns2:getAllIssueHistoriesResponse>
     <return>
        <eventDate>2013-08-02T11:45:58.013+02:00</eventDate>
        <eventText>Test</eventText>
        <issueEventType>
           <id>10</id>
           <value>Replied</value>
        </issueEventType>
     </return>
     <return>...</return>
     <return>...</return>
 </ns2:getAllIssueHistoriesResponse>
 </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

I am trying to extract all return nodes that have and issueEventType  value of 10.

I have used to following code in an attempt to achieve this where p_xml_content is my clob containing xml:

```
 l_xml_parser := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><results>';
 l_xml_parser := l_xml_parser ||(xmltype(p_xml_content).extract('//return/issueEventType/[id=10]').getclobval());
 l_xml_parser := l_xml_parser ||'</results>';
```

This returns nothing despite there definitely being an issueEventType  with a value of 10 within the xml document.

I've tried this with multiple variations such as:

```
  l_xml_parser := l_xml_parser ||(xmltype(p_xml_content).extract('//return/issueEventType[id=''10'']').getclobval());
```

And

```
  l_xml_parser := l_xml_parser ||(xmltype(p_xml_content).extract('//return/issueEventType/[@id=''10'']').getclobval());
```

But still nothing is returned.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was with the XPATH definition. Something is being returned but it is not what I expected. I wanted the entire return node that contains the id as a child node. To return this, the following is required:

```
  l_xml_parser := l_xml_parser ||(xmltype(p_xml_content).extract('//return/issueEventType/[id=10] /../.').getclobval());
```

The /../. in the XPATH tells the statement that when it finds and id of 10, it need to go up 1 level to the parent. As the current node is issueEventType this would take us to the return tag that is required. However, we then need to define /. to tell the XPATH to retreive the current node which at this point in the return node. This will then return the correct return nodes as well as all the nodes that they contain.

Comment: You can simplify the XPath slightly: `//return[issueEventType/id=10]` should also work.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to be a little more careful with XML namespaces.

The XML fragment you've posted isn't well-formed, as it doesn't have a namespace binding for the `soap` nor the `ns2` namespaces.  Let's add them in and see what happens:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2      p_xml_content   VARCHAR2(32767) := '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns2="http://www.your-url.com/">
  3   <soap:Body>
  4   <ns2:getAllIssueHistoriesResponse>
  5       <return>
  6          <eventDate>2013-08-02T11:45:58.013+02:00</eventDate>
  7          <eventText>Test</eventText>
  8          <issueEventType>
  9             <id>10</id>
 10             <value>Replied</value>
 11          </issueEventType>
 12       </return>
 13       <return>...</return>
 14       <return>...</return>
 15   </ns2:getAllIssueHistoriesResponse>
 16   </soap:Body>
 17   </soap:Envelope>';
 18
 19   l_xml_parser       VARCHAR2(32767);
 20  BEGIN
 21   l_xml_parser := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><results>';
 22   l_xml_parser := l_xml_parser ||(xmltype(p_xml_content).extract('//return/issueEventType[id=10]').getclobval());
 23   l_xml_parser := l_xml_parser ||'</results>';
 24
 25   dbms_output.put_line(l_xml_parser);
 26
 27  END;
 28  /
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><results><issueEventType>
  <id>10</id>

<value>Replied</value>
</issueEventType>
</results>

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

It all seemed to work.  We got some output.  So how come you're not getting any?

I'm afraid I'm going to have to guess here.  Given that you've already omitted two namespace bindings from your XML document, I'm going to assume that you've omitted at least one more, and amongst those that you've omitted is one that binds the default namespace prefix to a non-empty URL.  (In other words, your XML document has an attribute that looks like  `xmlns="..."`.)  What happens if we add this namespace binding to your XML document?

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2      p_xml_content   VARCHAR2(32767) := '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns2="http://www.your-url.com/" xmlns="http://www.example.com/">
  3   <soap:Body>
  4   <ns2:getAllIssueHistoriesResponse>
  5       <return>
  6          <eventDate>2013-08-02T11:45:58.013+02:00</eventDate>
  7          <eventText>Test</eventText>
  8          <issueEventType>
  9             <id>10</id>
 10             <value>Replied</value>
 11          </issueEventType>
 12       </return>
 13       <return>...</return>
 14       <return>...</return>
 15   </ns2:getAllIssueHistoriesResponse>
 16   </soap:Body>
 17   </soap:Envelope>';
 18
 19   l_xml_parser       VARCHAR2(32767);
 20  BEGIN
 21   l_xml_parser := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><results>';
 22   l_xml_parser := l_xml_parser ||(xmltype(p_xml_content).extract('//return/issueEventType[id=10]').getclobval());
 23   l_xml_parser := l_xml_parser ||'</results>';
 24
 25   dbms_output.put_line(l_xml_parser);
 26
 27  END;
 28  /
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-30625: method dispatch on NULL SELF argument is disallowed
ORA-06512: at line 22
```

Clearly this didn't work.

What happened here is that the call to `extract` returned `NULL`.  You can't then call `getclobval()` on `NULL`, and that's what gives you the ORA-30625 error.  The call to `extract` returned `NULL` because nothing matched your XPath expression.

An unqualified (i.e. unprefixed) name in an XPath expression *always* refers to a name in the 'default' namespace.  You have three such names, `return`, `issueEventType` and `id`.  In your XPath expression, these names are all in the namespace whose URI is the empty string.  In your XML document, you have elements with names `return`, `issueEventType` and `id` in the namespace with URI `http://www.example.com/`.  Because the namespace URIs differ, the elements are not considered to match.

The fix to this problem is to bind another prefix to the same URI as what you have the default prefix bound to, and use that prefix in your XPath expression.   The `extract` method takes an optional second parameter which specifies additional prefixes to bind to namespaces, and the format for this is exactly the same as the 'attributes' you specify to bind a prefix to a namespace in XML.  Instead of writing

```
    l_xml_parser := l_xml_parser ||(xmltype(p_xml_content).extract('//return/issueEventType[id=10]').getclobval());
```

write

```
    l_xml_parser := l_xml_parser ||(xmltype(p_xml_content).extract('//e:return/e:issueEventType[e:id=10]', 'xmlns:e="http://www.example.com/"').getclobval());
```

Here, we bind the prefix `e` to the same URI as that bound to the default prefix, and we then qualify the names `return`, `issueEventType` and `id` with this prefix.  You can use a different prefix if you prefer, as long as you use it consistently.

Lo and behold, this works:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2      p_xml_content   VARCHAR2(32767) := '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns2="http://www.your-url.com/" xmlns="http://www.example.com/">
  3   <soap:Body>
  4   <ns2:getAllIssueHistoriesResponse>
  5       <return>
  6          <eventDate>2013-08-02T11:45:58.013+02:00</eventDate>
  7          <eventText>Test</eventText>
  8          <issueEventType>
  9             <id>10</id>
 10             <value>Replied</value>
 11          </issueEventType>
 12       </return>
 13       <return>...</return>
 14       <return>...</return>
 15   </ns2:getAllIssueHistoriesResponse>
 16   </soap:Body>
 17   </soap:Envelope>';
 18
 19   l_xml_parser       VARCHAR2(32767);
 20  BEGIN
 21   l_xml_parser := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><results>';
 22   l_xml_parser := l_xml_parser ||(xmltype(p_xml_content).extract('//e:return/e:issueEventType[e:id=10]', 'xmlns:e="http://www.example.com/"').getclobval());
 23   l_xml_parser := l_xml_parser ||'</results>';
 24
 25   dbms_output.put_line(l_xml_parser);
 26
 27  END;
 28  /
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><results><issueEventType
xmlns="http://www.example.com/">
  <id>10</id>

<value>Replied</value>
</issueEventType>
</results>

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is incorrect. At least in my case. The namespaces were there. See my solution below. It was actually an error with the xpath.

Comment: @jezzipin: So your comments about nothing being returned are wrong?  If you are going to ask a question that doesn't accurately describe your problem, expect wrong answers.